# Juniper Steel Belted Radius SBR JDBC Connection String

Tags: mysql, jdbc, solaris, dsn

i have a maybe simple question but i need help

there is a Radius server that needs to be connected to mysql database using jdbc driver but I didn't get the connection string right

what i did is

"Connect=DSN=jdbc:mysql://x.x.x.x:3306/SteelBeltedRadius; UID=xxxx;PWD=xxxxx "

but i get the " initial SQL connect attempt failed "

I'm using

OS: SUN SOLARIS 10,

MySQL-server: 5.5.27